# Establecer un patrón de expresiones regulares alfanuméricas que no acepta ciertos símbolos específicos

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, validación

```py
import re

#Examples:
input_text = "Recien el 2021-10-12 despues de 3 dias 2021-10-12" #NOT PASS
input_text = "Recien el 2021-10-12 hsah555sahsdhj. Ya despues de 3 dias hjsdfhjdsfhjdsf 2021-10-12" #NOT PASS
input_text = "Recien el 2021-10-12 hsah555sahsdhj; despues de 3 dias hjsdfhjdsfhjdsf 2021-10-12" #NOT PASS
input_text = "Recien el 2021-10-12 hsah555sahsdhj despues de 3 dias hjsdfhjdsfhjdsf.\n 2021-10-12" #NOT PASS
input_text = "Recien el 2021-10-12 hsah555sahsdhj; mmm... creo que ya despues de 3 dias hjsdfhjdsfhjdsf.\n 2021-10-12" #PASS
input_text = "Recien el 2021-10-12 hsah555sahsdhj.    \n\n\n mmm... creo que ya despues de 3 dias hjsdfhjdsfhjdsf.\n 2021-10-12" #PASS


some_text = r"[\s|]*"  # <--- I NEED MODIFY THIS PATTERN
date_format = r"\d*-\d{2}-\d{2}"

check_00 = re.search(date_format + some_text + r"(?:(?:pasados|pasado|despues del|despues de el|despues de|despues|tras) (\d+) (?:días|día|dias|dia)|(\d+) (?:días|día|dias|dia) (?:pasados|pasado|despues del|despues de el|despues de|despues|tras))", input_text, re.IGNORECASE)
check_01 = re.search(r"(?:(?:pasados|pasado|despues del|despues de el|despues de|despues|tras) (\d+) (?:días|día|dias|dia)|(\d+) (?:días|día|dias|dia) (?:pasados|pasado|despues del|despues de el|despues de|despues|tras))" + some_text + date_format, input_text, re.IGNORECASE)

if not check_00 and not check_01: print("1")
else: print("0")
```

Necesito establecer en la variable `some_text` un patrón que identifique cualquier subcadena alfanumérica (que posiblemente podría contener símbolos incluidos, como `:` , `$`, `#`, `&`, `?`, `¿`, `!`, `¡`, `|`, `°`, `,` , `.`, `(`, `)`, `]`, `[`, `}`, `{` ), y con la posibilidad de contener caracteres en mayúsculas y minúsculas, **pero los únicos símbolos que no deben estar presentes, ni siquiera una vez, son** `;` **y** `.\n` **o de forma mas general seria** `.[\s|]*\n*`

En este caso, necesito determinar qué casos NO cumplen, por lo tanto, los condicionales `if not` en el código.

El **output** que debería obtener si todo en el algoritmo funciona bien sería este:

```
0  #for example 1
0  #for example 2
0  #for example 3
0  #for example 4
1  #for example 5
1  #for example 6
```

¿Es posible, dentro del mismo patrón que quiero colocar en la variable `some_text`, indicar una lista con los símbolos que NO quiero que aparezcan en esa zona de identificación del patrón (en este caso el punto y coma `;` y el punto y aparte `.[\s|]*\n*` ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El RE que necesitas, es este:

```
[^\.;\n]*
```

Respondiendo a tu pregunta final, si, es posible especificar una lista de caracteres o simbolos que no queres que coincidan en el patron de la expresion regular. Lo podes hacer usando la sintaxis de clase de caracteres negados (^).

Por ejemplo:

```
[^abc] va a coincidir con cualquier caracter que no sea a, b o c
```